# Keyframes and Animations do not work in Next js at all

Tags: css-animations, next.js, styled-jsx

I'm using styled jsx in Next.js to style my components and  many times i have found myself struggling with getting the animations working.

so i've created the example below to demonstrate the problem which is that it seems animations and key frames don't work in styled jsx so my question is am i right? if I'm then is there a workaround for me to use animations and keyframes for my components?

here is my animation component which should show a simple animation from red to yellow

```
const Animation = () =>{
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <section className="wrapper">
            <p>
                <b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.
            </p>

            <div></div>

            <p>
                <b>Note:</b> When an animation is finished, it changes back to its original style.
            </p>
                <style jsx> {`
                            div {
                                width: 100px;
                                height: 100px;
                                background-color: red;
                                -webkit-animation-name: example; 
                                -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
                                animation-name: example;
                                animation-duration: 4s;
                            }


                            @-webkit-keyframes example {
                                from {background-color: red;}
                                to {background-color: yellow;}
                            }


                            @keyframes example {
                                from {background-color: red;}
                                to {background-color: yellow;}
                            }
                `}
                </style>
            </section>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Animation
```

and here is the result which acts as i have not included an animation at all and displays a static red box !

[image]

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @Taio i ended up using different files for css and write the animation at that file since the developers said animations aren't supported in styled jsx at the time

Comment: @Taio if you want to add a separate css file you have to add another folder with the exact name of "static" and then create the css file there and then you can import it in any component you like